# "AAPT2 error: check logs for details" and other issues

Tags: concatenation

I'm getting a lot of errors. Mainly saying "cannot resolve symbol R". I've done a full clean and rebuild many times. This started to happen when I updated, (which I regret at this point) then I had issues with this:

```
    * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
    */
   private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
       TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
       quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfCoffees);
   }
```

At "" + numberOfCoffess it says "do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string placeholders

Comment: Everything is solved. I've done a Clean and Rebuild multiple times. I've also done an Invalidate and Restart before and it didn't work. I've decided to do the Invalidate and Restart again and it worked for me this time.

Comment: Most of everything is solved except for the last issue.